# Comment s'appelle le vêtement vert du petit prince ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, habillement

Comment s'appelle le vêtement vert du petit prince: « jupe » ou « robe » (ou un autre mot) ?

Comment: On peut connaitre la raison de ce vote négatif ?

Answer (score 5):

Je me base sur cette image:

[image]

Il ne s'agit ni une jupe ni une robe car il y a des jambes.

A partir de là soit c'est un vêtement en une pièce et dans ce cas cela s'appelle une `combinaison`, soit c'est un vêtement en 2 pièces et chacune des pièces a un nom, `pantalon` pour le bas et je dirais `chemise` pour le haut (à priori)

Comment: Pour perfectionner: A-t-il ses mains dans « les poches de pantalon » ?

Comment: Si la question est de savoir comment cela se dite, il s'agit d'une différente question, mais effectivement dire qu'il a les mains dans "les poches de [son] pantalon" est correct. On dira plus couramment qu'il a "les mains dans les poches" ou "les mains en poches"

Comment: @ Laurent S. Quel dommage vous n'êtes pas près de moi - j'aimerais- vous à corriger ma raconte.

Comment: C'est un peu comme pour les jupes-culotte des femmes : on peu dire qu'il a les mains dans les poches de sa culotte. (**par exemple**, (TLFi) Des knickerbockers, charmantes culottes anglaises qui se bouclent sous le genou et retombent sur la jambe (COCTEAU, Gd écart, 1923, p. 88).)

Comment: "j'aimerais- vous à corriger ma raconte" > je crois avoir compris le sens général, mais cette phrase n'est pas correcte du tout. Si par hasard vous étiez en train d'écrire une histoire où le texte français est important, je vous conseillerais d'encore progresser un peu. Mais rassurez-vous, votre français est déjà bien meilleur que mon Allemand qui se résume à quelques chansons de Rammstein (et 99 luftballons :-))

Comment: (j'aimerais que vous corrigiez mon récit ?)

Comment: @ Laurent S. J'avais écrit un récit en allemand et maintenant je suis en train de faire une traduction, aidé par mes  vielles connaissances d'école et pages web comme de.pons.com, translate.systran.net ou ici, ma dernière trouvaille. Malheureusement je ne peux pas payer un tradructeur professionel - mais l'autre côte : J'aime cet experiment et peux à peux les vielles connaissances reviennent.